# Highcharts: alone point hard not visible with marked disabled

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

Highchart with some null points (alone point only visible via tooltip if marker disabled):

[image]

[image]

Adding marker enabled will fix the issue of invisible point, but it can be "ugly" if there are many points to be displayed:

[image]

[image]

Anybody has a suggestion about how I could make an alone point more visible, without cramming my graphs with markers? More precisely, I'd like to show marker only on alone points.

Answer (score 2):

Highcharts are pretty flexible in the way how you configure your representation. you can configure marker per point:

http://jsfiddle.net/dfaqq1v0/

```
   series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [ 1, 0, 3, null, 
                {
                  y:2, 
                  marker:{ enabled:true }
                },
               null, 3, 1, 2, 1],
        marker:{
            enabled:false
        }
    }]
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll try that. I guess I want to make it generally applicable such that either points with *no sibblings, single sibbling, or sibbling(s) == null* have markers